# NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds iPhone X+

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsattributedstring

I am getting

```
NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'
```

caused by

```
self.descr.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: restaurant.longDescription, attributes: self.descr.attributedText?.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil))
```

works fine on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, but crashes on iPhone 6+. What might be the reason?